# C# RichTextBox change selected to bold or none selected to bold

Tags: c#, fonts, richtextbox

Hi im doing a project and part of is to. If i type somthing in a RichTextBox en press my Bold button everyting should be Bold but if i have selected text then only that should be Bold. If nothing is in the RichTextBox a message should be displayed. Im still a student so my coding is not that experienced.
This is what i have so far or trying:

[I took a snippet of my code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RUy41.png)

```
private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (rtbText.TextLength == 0)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Textbox is empty");
    }
    else if 
    {
        rtbText.Font = new System.Drawing.Font (rtbText.Font.Name,
        rtbText.Font.Size, rtbText.Font.Style ^ System.Drawing.FontStyle.Bold);
    }
    else
    {
        rtbText.SelectionFont = new Font(rtbText.Font, FontStyle.Bold);
        rtbText.SelectionStart = rtbText.SelectionStart + rtbText.SelectionLength;
        rtbText.SelectionLength = 0;
        rtbText.SelectionFont = rtbText.Font;
    }
}
```

Comment: Add your code as text to question

Comment: the else if and the else is not completed but i just need like a guideline

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you are looking for correct `if` conditions, try this code:

```
if (rtbText.TextLength == 0)
{
}
else if (rtbText.SelectionLength == 0)
{
}
else
{
}
```

Comment: @Dreyer does I answered your question? If so accept it. If not please edit answer and clarify requirements

Comment: Im sorry im still new. You did anwser my question and again thank you so much